# Build pyramid in SQL (ORACLE)

Tags: sql, oracle

I saw it before, but I don't have any idea how to build it?
May be some one have any idea)

I need to get result like:

```
1
11
111
1111
11111
```

Comment: Should the size be variable, or are you just wanting output identical to your question example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select rpad('1',level, '1') 
from dual
connect by level <= 10;
```

Output:

```
1
11
111
1111
11111
111111
1111111
11111111
111111111
1111111111
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select      lpad('1',level,'1')
from        dual
connect by  level <= 5
```